# any jsf plugin to facilitate design UI?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

Maybe my question is a newbie one, but I can not really understand the circumstances under which design web application in java?

i used JSF for developing java web application , can i found any plugins or frame work in order to facilitate designing steps?

Comment: You question is to broader. Please be more specific.

Comment: can i found any plugins or frame work in order to facilitate designing steps ?

Comment: Which designing steps?

Comment: i mean such ADF components in JSF can i found any plugin to add into netbeans to facilitate design steps ?

Comment: I strongly encourage you not to use any WYSIWYG plugins for IDEs in order to do not only JSF development, but any kind of HTML development. They will make a mess of your code. Instead, write the code yourself and test it in one (or more than one) proper real web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PrimeFaces for free: http://primefaces.org

Also you can (optionally) buy templates and themes from: http://www.primefaces.org/themes